# Function executes correctly only on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple JS code that on "text-title" element click checks if another element exists and if it does it add class to third element. Problem is that function works properly only in user clicks twice on "text-title" element. I also tried to console.log   "(.fpd-layouts-panel .fpd-item).length" element and I get correct value only on second click.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my JS code:

```
jQuery('.text-title').click( function() {
  
  if (jQuery('.fpd-layouts-panel .fpd-item').length) {
    jQuery('.ux-swatch[data-value="caseotic"]').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    jQuery('.ux-swatch[data-value="caseotic"]').addClass('hidden');
  };
});
```

And HTML code:

```
<div class="fpd-item fpd-tooltip text-title tooltipstered selected" data-title="iPhone 12" data-source="http://localhost:8888/wp-testi/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/iphone-13.jpg">iPhone 12 </div>

<div class="ux-swatch tooltip ux-swatch--image tooltipstered" data-value="caseotic" data-name="CASEOTIC"><img width="100" height="100" src="http://localhost:8888/wp-testi/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/CASEOTIC-IPHONE-13-100x100.jpg" class="ux-swatch__img attachment-woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail size-woocommerce_gallery_thumbnail" alt="CASEOTIC" loading="lazy" srcset="http://localhost:8888/wp-testi/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/CASEOTIC-IPHONE-13-100x100.jpg 100w, http://localhost:8888/wp-testi/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/CASEOTIC-IPHONE-13-510x510.jpg 510w, http://localhost:8888/wp-testi/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/CASEOTIC-IPHONE-13.jpg 650w" sizes="(max-width: 100px) 100vw, 100px"><span class="ux-swatch__text">CASEOTIC</span></div>


<div class="fpd-layouts-panel">
            <div class="fpd-scroll-area mCustomScrollbar _mCS_6 mCS-autoHide mCS_no_scrollbar" style="position: relative; overflow: visible;"><div id="mCSB_6" class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light mCSB_vertical mCSB_outside" tabindex="0" style="max-height: none;"><div id="mCSB_6_container" class="mCSB_container mCS_y_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_y" style="position:relative; top:0; left:0;" dir="ltr">
                <div class="fpd-grid"><div class="fpd-item fpd-tooltip tooltipstered"><picture style="background-image: url(http://localhost:8888/wp-testi/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/CASEOTIC-IPHONE-13.jpg" );"=""></picture></div></div>
            </div></div><div id="mCSB_6_scrollbar_vertical" class="mCSB_scrollTools mCSB_6_scrollbar mCS-light mCSB_scrollTools_vertical mCSB_scrollTools_onDrag_expand" style="display: none;"><div class="mCSB_draggerContainer"><div id="mCSB_6_dragger_vertical" class="mCSB_dragger" style="position: absolute; min-height: 30px; height: 0px; top: 0px;"><div class="mCSB_dragger_bar" style="line-height: 30px;"></div><div class="mCSB_draggerRail"></div></div></div></div></div>
        </div>
```

And in advance thank you all for helping.

Comment: Well, it sounds like there aren't any elements that would match `.fpd-layouts-panel .fpd-item` on the first click. Are you sure they do exist in the DOM before the first click?

Comment: Yes, on load there is one '.fpd-layouts-panel .fpd-item' element that exist.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? If you add `console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".fpd-layouts-panel .fpd-item"))` (which is the same selection jQuery does) to that function, does a list of elements appear in the console?

Comment: Yes, I get: length:1

Comment: @MiranUrbas Please include all relevant code like html

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I also added HTML code

Comment: @MiranUrbas Look at the picture element in your html, there is something wrong in the `style`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen you mean (="") this?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible snippet?  See [mcve].   Emphasis on *minimal reproducible* - something we can actually see, there's too much single-line HTML at the moment.  It seems that your issue would not be re-creatable outside your specific code.

Comment: The issue with `picture` is that you have `style="background-image:url(url");"="" - ie an extra dodgy quote inside the url which is breaking your generated code

Comment: @freedomn-m is it ok if I share link to website here? This is WP project.

Comment: Ideally not, it should be re-creatable in the question.  Your site will change over time so will mean this question has no value (in the future, see [tour] *build a library of detailed, high-quality answers*).  Having said that, you do have *some* code in your question, so it may be useful as "an extra resource" (rather than the only resource). See [Something in my web site doesn't work, can I paste a link to it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Here's a recreation of the code *as provided*, with only the html relevant to the code provided:  https://jsfiddle.net/du9s2684/  It's unclear what you would expect to happen on 2nd/3rd click as there's no change (as provided) to .fpd-item.

Comment: @freedomn-m .fpd-item does change based on text-title selection. Lets say first text-title item should give one .fpd-item element, second .text-title element gives zero .fpd-item elements. There are about 10 different text-title elements that gives 1 or 0 .fpd-item

Comment: Hence the need to provided a *reproducible* snippet.  If we can't see the code doing what you say it's doing, while the code you've provided (and only that code) *clearly* doesn't do what you say, then we can't help you.  Now you're adding some other, totally unmentioned feature that ".fpd-item does change" - where/how/when?  Reproducible snippet.

Comment: @freedomn-m OK, I will try to add reproducible snippet.